# How to iterate an Entity Framework tree to find a specific item

Tags: entity-framework, tree, iteration

I have loaded my product catalog using Entity Framework

I would like to iterate all items to find a specific item
the structure is 
Category -> [Subcategory ->] Product -> options
Subcategory, product and options are EntityCollection of their specific type
All types derive from EntityObject

Let's say I'm looking for option 12 but I don't know in which product it is in.

How can I iterate all objects to find the option 12 ? I have this so far. in my EntityObject, I know it's not recursive yet but will eventually be once i know which properties are collections, I might be approaching it the wrong way ...

```
public T Find<T>(Type type, int id) where T : EntityObject
        {    
            //get all properties 
            PropertyInfo[] properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
            // foreach property find the one
            foreach (PropertyInfo oPropertyInfo in properties)
            {
                // check for type
                if (oPropertyInfo.PropertyType == type)
                {
                    PersistentEntity o = oPropertyInfo.GetValue(this, null) as EntityObject;
                    if (o != null && o.Id == id)
                    {
                        return (T)o;
                    }                        
                }
                // if property has childs, is IEnumerable -> recursive
            }


            return (T)new EntityObject();
        }
```

Comment: This is wrong approach because it demands to load whole content of all your tables into memory. You should build correct linq query for each requested scenario and return only entities satisfying the condition.

Comment: I know it's the wrong approach to load all the structure in memory but that is the approach I'm stuck with.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var query = 
from c in categories
from sc in c.SubCategories
from from p in sc.Products
from o in p.Options
where o.Id == 2
select c /* or p?? */;
```

Comment: The thing is the user might request a different object like Category , subcategory or product also using and id, I want the user to be able to select the item type to look for

Comment: But something needs to know about the relationship. You can't do it completely dynamically...Unless I'm misunderstanding your question.